# Numerical optimization over separable measurements

Tags: measurement, information-theory, optimization

For a set of bipartite density operators $\{\rho_a\}_{a=1}^m \subset D(\mathcal{X} \otimes \mathcal{Y})$ each associated with a probability $p(a)$, an optimal separable measurement is a POVM $\{ \Lambda_k\}_{k=1}^m \subset \text{Pos}(\mathcal{X} \otimes \mathcal{Y})$ achieving
\begin{equation}
\max_{ \{\Lambda_k\}} \sum_{a=1}^m p(a) \text{Tr}(\Lambda_a  \rho_a)
\end{equation}

such that every $\Lambda_k$ is a seperable operator. The optimal separable measurement problem consists of finding such a maximizer for any fixed choice of problem setup. I have read in several places that this is an NP-hard problem and I understand this basically arises from the set of separable operators being nonconvex.

#### Question

How do you approximate this optimization numerically (for arbitrary local dimensions)? And what is the hardness of this optimization problem in a practical setting: What kinds of optimizers are used for this task, do they perform well, and is there ever any guarantee on the closeness of the solution to a true optimum?

Comment: A related optimization over a separable set is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.05218v3)(eq.39) and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.08055).

Comment: Met recently:https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0808, but I didn't read it. The abstract shows it's a closely related paper.